# Creating a REST API for telnet connection

Tags: python, rest, flask, telnet

I am working with a server that allows me to connect over telnet. I need to send it a few commands and return what they sent.

```
class LSController:
def __init__(self, ssh_ip, ssh_user, ssh_pass, telnet_port):
    server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (ssh_ip, 22),
    ssh_username=ssh_user,
    ssh_password=ssh_pass,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', telnet_port)
    )

    server.start()
    HOST = "localhost"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,server.local_bind_port)
    self.tn = tn        

    #get initial info
    tn.read_until('')
    tn.write('request.all\n')
    tn.read_until('END')

def send_command(self, command):
    self.tn.write(command + '\n')
    return self.tn.read_until('END')
```

I'd like to create a simple REST API around it using Flask. What is the best way to approach this?

For example one of the commands I want to have is:

```
    send_command('queue mytrack.mp3')
```